# Server side JSON string validation

Tags: javascript, php, json, security

Is there a secure way to validate an incoming untrusted JSON string in php?

The client shows a dynamic form. The user can enter data into that form. The data needs to be saved on the server. The server will not work with the data, it will only pass it on to the client the next time the page is loaded in order to restore the forms values. Therefore I **do not** want to check every value separately and save it into its own database field.

I want to save it as a JSON string and insert it into the DOM as a object variable on every page load. Is there a secure way to sanitize the incoming JSON string for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "sanitize"?

Comment: Why not store the data in a cookie or a session?

Comment: @lonesomeday Make it ready to insert it into the DOM like `var insertedJSON = "{'field' : 'value'}"` by removing any potentially dangeroues parts (like closing quotation marks, 'ending' the object and running other code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're injecting the code into a `script` tag and you want to guarantee that it is pure Javascript code, without any potentially dangerous XSS vulnerabilities, the simple way would be to use PHP first to decode it and then to re-encode it.

```
$safeJSON = json_encode(json_decode($unsafeJSON));
```

Anything that is invalid JSON will return `null` when `json_decode` is called on it. In this case, the string `"null"` would be returned to your browser, which is unlikely to do any harm in this context!

---

It's worth noting, however, that what you are doing is only potentially unsafe because this is not actually JSON. When it's being used inside a `script` tag, it's simply a Javascript object literal. If you were using it as JSON, e.g. by doing an AJAX call, it would not be a security vulnerability because the browser will not recognise invalid JSON in a `JSON.parse` call. See [this excellent blog post](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) for more information on the difference between Javascript objects and JSON.